# Runner number recognising

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I work for a company that makes photos of running competitions and uploads them to a web, so that the runners can download them. The problem is that the company can make more thatn 2000 photos for each competition and it can be very dificult for the runner to find himself. So the company have asked me to develop an application that indexes all the photos by the runner number.

I have tried with aplying an OCR to all the image with no results.
I have no idea from where to start. Is there any algorithm that searches for a given object?i mean, i could have an example photo of one number and look for similar subimages in the photos.

The computation time doesn´t matter, since the photos would be preprocessed before uploading them to the web.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how do the runners look? What makes them look different from the rest of the world? Look at what they wear, find something common to all the runners and uncommon to the rest of the scene, and try to search for something that resembles the "search parameters" for the runner.